# Filtering strings out of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, filter, .net-3.5

I'm trying to design a check on incoming strings for an array, and if the incoming string has a specific starting character it gets skipped over

For example:

```
;item1
item2
item3
;item4
```

should be put into array as

```
item2
item3
```

I thought I'd try to use a foreach method to skip the line that starts with the identifier, and then in the else append the lines that don't match back into the string array, but it doesn't seem I am able to do this.

Help!

```
    void Whitelist()
    {
        if (logging == 1)
        {
            FIO._Log("Performing WhiteList func", writer);
        }
        try
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Whitelist.ini");
            string[] lines2;
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith(";"))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    // lines2.append(line) ??
                }

            }
            structs.CustomWhiteList = lines2;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error reading whitelist file." + Environment.NewLine + e.Message);
            FIO._Log("Failed to read whitelist file", writer);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use [IEnumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: You have an array, not a list. There's no "Add" or "Append" method. But everything can be shortened to `lines2 = lines.Where(l => !l.StartsWith(";"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the lines in, filter out the ones starting with a semicolon, and then set the resulting array directly to `CustomWhiteList`.

Try the following code:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("Whitelist.ini");

structs.CustomWhiteList = lines.Where(x => !x.StartsWith(";")).ToArray();
```

This uses LINQ, so you'll have to add `using System.Linq` to your class if it's not already there.

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you! Everyone had good answers, but this one was so simple, and you answered me so fast.